# AWS API Gateway: Status Code 413, Request Entity too large

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a server less API with AWS API Gateway and Lambda function. I am using custom authorization function for authorization. The header is too large and due to which I am getting this error. Normally, for an nginx server, I would have changed the nging config and this would have been fixed. I don't know how to take care of this in AWS API Gateway.

Comment: Which header is too large? The one client send to API GW, or the token passed to the authorizer, or an integration header? What's do the Test Invoke logs show?

Comment: @Balaji I checked again and this API is not even using custom authorizer. It's the header the client is sending to the API GW.

Comment: I have exactly same problem and request is reaching the custom authorizer. I get 413 if I pass a pdf in body greater than 10MB. Should it be api gateway issue if request is reaching the custom authorizer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 10MB payload limit applies to the message body. If you're running into limits on the header size, unfortunately these cannot be configured. They are stated on the CloudFront page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html

In particular:

> Custom headers: maximum length of a header name 256 characters
>
> Custom headers: maximum length of a header value 2,048 characters
>
> Custom headers: maximum length of all header values and names combined 10,240 characters

Answer (score 8):

The limit for payload size currently cannot be changed. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html:

> 10MB payload size, which cannot be changed currently.

If you want more customization, you should run your API on an actual server (e.g. with Amazon EC2).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this when trying to upload files, make sure your file types are defined in the Settings portion of your API (in the tree under your API name in API Gateway). We encountered this error and both 500 and 502's when troubleshooting this. First thing was an RDS setting (we were calling the reader instance, not the writer when trying to edit). Next was the missing file types in our API settings. Those two changes got us to 200's - so bear in mind that the 413 error is a bit deceptive. For context, we are using the API Gateway with lambda functions in our web app. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but if you're using Express JS on the back-end with the bodyParser middleware, that might be what's stopping you. You can update the size limit by defining the `limit` property in the config object passed to bodyParser:

```js
app.use(express.json({ limit: '200kb' }));
```

You can change the value to whatever suits your needs, the docs are [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit).

Answer (score 1):

I found that gunzipping the content solves this issue (code inspired from this blog post https://techblog.commercetools.com/gzip-on-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-5170bb02b543)

See this example with Typescript:

```js
export async function getResponse(savedItems) {
  return new Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>((resolve, reject) => zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify(savedItems), (error, gzippedResponse) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      const response: APIGatewayProxyResult = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
          'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        },
        isBase64Encoded: true,
        body: gzippedResponse.toString('base64'),
      };
      console.info(`response statusCode: ${response.statusCode} body length: ${response.body.length}`);
      resolve(response);
    }
  }));
}
```